# Swift: UITableView scrolls back to top when section header height is changed dynamically

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, swift2

[image: while scrolling]!

[image: expanded view]

I have a tableView with a single section. The header of this section holds the Sort By label and the three ImageViews. The view below it is a UITableViewCell.

The first image shows the initial view of the section header. When the header is clicked (have added a tap gesture), I expand the section view by changing the constant of the height constraint programmatically (have created an outlet for the height constraint).

Everything works fine, the section header expands as desired. However the tableviewcell scrolls right to the top again. Meaning, if when the section header was not expanded and I had scrolled down to some level, as soon as the header view expands, the entire offset is lost and tableviewcell scrolls right back to the top. I do not want this. I want the table view cell to remain  where it is and for the section header to expand and collapse over it. How can I achieve this? Please help.

Comment: Can you show me the code where you're reloading Data when tap on Sort by..

Comment: I have same issue on my tableview. When i close a section and there are no open sections it scrolls to the top.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you might be doing this:

```
setContentOffset(CGPointZero, animated: true)
```

which you shouldn't do.

Comment: No, I didn't do that.

Comment: @OscarOrcas you need to provide some code, otherwise it is impossible to help you.